# how to have a enemy be added in every 10 seconds and have this enemy track your location and follow it

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

im currently working on an app in which your player which is a small round ball, gets dragged around the screen by your finger. Then every 10 seconds a enemy ball gets added in which automatically tracks your ball and follows it until it runs into it. this is the code I have for this so far. you can drag your ball around the screen, bu the enemy ball which is only showing up as a red x even though its file is in the assets gets spawned every frame and they just move to the position of where your ball was when it was spawned. is there any way I can fix this, any help is appreciated. the contact between the balls I will add later on.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


var me = SKSpriteNode()
let enemy = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "ellipse 1")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    me = self.childNode(withName: "me") as! SKSpriteNode

    let border = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = border
               }



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        me.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0))
        me.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0))
    }

}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        me.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0))
        me.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0))
    }
}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        let enemy = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "ball 2")
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x:667, y: -200)
    enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: me.position.x, duration: 1.5))
    enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: me.position.y, duration: 1.5))
    enemy.zPosition = +1
    addChild(enemy)


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So the problem you're having is that your enemy ball images aren't loading, and you're seeing a red X instead?

If so you need to break your code that creates your sprite into steps. First load the image into a temporary variable, print it, and then use the image to create your sprite:

```
let enemyImage = imageNamed: "ellipse 1"
print("enemyImage = \(enemyImage)")
let enemy = SKSpriteNode (enemyImage)
```

If `enemyImage` is nil, you need to figure out why that is.

Comment: this still didn't work, but thats not a main issue, I can fix that later, my real problem is how can I change them from getting spawned every frame to every 10 seconds. also, they only follow the balls coordinates to where it was when it spawned if I move my ball after that, the enemy doesn't follow

Comment: Check the current time in update. If it's more than 10 seconds since the last spawn, spawn a new enemy and save the current time as the last spawn time. Better yet, just create and SKAction to run every 10 seconds to do the spawn.

Comment: how exactly would I do that skaction method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code that'll spawn an enemy once every 10 seconds and have them follow you. I used the Spaceship graphic provided by Apple's SpriteKit template for the enemy. As for your issue with the enemy graphic not showing up I'd make sure that the image is named "ball 2" in the assets folder.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {
    var enemySpeed: CGFloat = 4
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var me: SKSpriteNode!
    var enemies = [Enemy]()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        me = self.childNode(withName: "me") as! SKSpriteNode
        let border = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = border
        spawnEnemy() // Spawn an enemy to begin with
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(spawnEnemy), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) // Spawns an enemy every 10 seconds
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy = Enemy(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        enemy.xScale = 0.25
        enemy.yScale = 0.25
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(size.width)) - size.width / 2, y: CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(size.height)) - size.height / 2)
        enemy.zPosition = 1
        addChild(enemy)
        enemies.append(enemy)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            me.run(SKAction.move(to: location, duration: 0.05))
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            me.run(SKAction.move(to: location, duration: 0.05))
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        for enemy in enemies {
            let angle = CGFloat(atan2f(Float(me.position.y - enemy.position.y), Float(me.position.x - enemy.position.x)))
            enemy.zRotation = angle - CGFloat.pi / 2
            enemy.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x + cos(angle) * enemy.enemySpeed, y: enemy.position.y + sin(angle) * enemy.enemySpeed)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @mikeytdan, I came up with this. my issue is that it only follow me to the initial location I was when it spawned, then stops there. when I put it in the update function to make it run every frame I can't call it

Comment: The reason why your code isn't working is because you're creating a new enemy each frame. You tell the enemy to move towards your current position when they are first created. You don't keep a reference to them so there is no way to tell them to keep following you. In my example I keep track of all the enemies in an array. Every frame I tell the enemies to face and move toward the player's position.

Comment: yes, I figured that out, in my past comment I was referencing the code I just put in the answer area

Answer (score 0):

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var me = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        me = self.childNode(withName: "me") as! SKSpriteNode

        let border = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = border

        run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(createEnemy), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10.0)])))
    }

    func createEnemy () {

        let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball 1")
        enemy.name = "enemy"
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x:667, y: -200)

        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: me.position.x, duration: 1.5))
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: me.position.y, duration: 1.5))

        enemy.zPosition = +1
        addChild(enemy)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            me.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0))
            me.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0))
        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            me.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0))
            me.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0))
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {


    }
}
```